# What is the gradient of a matrix product AB?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

The sixth page of this http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf says that the gradient of $dYi, / dXi, = W$ but https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html says it is $GB^T$ on page 212, I am sure there is a gap in my understanding somewhere.  I understand how we get the first derivative but then what is $GB^T$, is that also the derivative (sorry if I'm using the words gradient and derivative interchangeably still trying to get a grasp on this subject).

Comment: Hi Sahil. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Just changed it thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\d{\delta}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Renaming the variables from the first reference from $(Y,X,W)\to(C,A,B)$ makes it comparable to the second reference, i.e. the basic relationship is
$$C=AB$$
In the second reference, there is a scalar cost function $z$ which is assumed to be a function of $C$. Not only that, but the gradient wrt $C$ is given by the following matrix
$$G=\grad{z}{C}$$
Then it proposes using the chain rule is to calculate the gradient wrt $A$.

**However**, it is easier to write the differential, then change the independent variable from $C\to A$
$$\eqalign{
dz &= G:dC \\
  &= G:\LR{dA\;B} \\
  &= GB^T:dA \\
\grad{z}{A} &= GB^T \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \trace{X^TY} \\
X:X &= \big\|X\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms
in such a product to be rearranged in many different but
equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= Y:X \\
X:Y &= X^T:Y^T \\
W:XY &= WY^T:X = X^TW:Y \\\\
}$$

---

Now back to the first reference. It is describing how to calculate something much more complicated $-$ the matrix-by-matrix gradient $\,\grad{C}{A}$

Once again, this can be calculated most easily using differentials
$$\eqalign{
C &= AB \\
C_{ij} &= \sum_{p=\o}^D A_{ip}\,B_{pj} \\
dC_{ij} &= \sum_{p=\o}^D dA_{ip}\,B_{pj} \\
\grad{C_{ij}}{A_{\ell k}}
 &= \sum_{p=\o}^D \grad{A_{ip}}{A_{\ell k}}\;B_{pj} \\
 &= \sum_{p=\o}^D \d_{i\ell}\,\d_{pk}\,B_{pj} \\
 &= \d_{i\ell}\,B_{kj} \\
}$$
The PDF then sets $\ell=i$ to evaluate the remaining Kronecker delta symbol as $\o$, however leaving the delta symbol intact yields a more general (and useful) result.

As you read more, you will discover that the field of *Machine Learning* uses a hodge-podge of mathematical notations.  Every book or article uses a different approach $-$ and most of them are terrible.

Comment: Hi greg thank you so much! I am just now beginning to learn about derivatives in the area of vectors and matrices so I really appreciate the help.  If you have any resources on how to learn more about these mathematical topics I would greatly appreciate them as I only have a primitive knowledge of partial derivatives and derivatives with matrices.